# How to put image aligned right, bottom in picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, image

i have picturebox1 much larger than image i'd like to load. What i want to do is aligned this image to right side, and bottom of picturebox like on screenshot:
[image]

Edit: Working

```
 private void FromCameraPictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        if (loadimage == true)
        {
            var image = new Bitmap(@"image.jpg");
            if (image != null)
            {
                var g = e.Graphics;
                // -- Optional -- //
                g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                // -- Optional -- //
                g.DrawImage(image,
                    FromCameraPictureBox.Width - image.Width,  // to right
                    FromCameraPictureBox.Height - image.Height, // to bottom
                    image.Width,
                    image.Height);
            }

       }
       loadimage = false;
    }
```

and now i want to fire paintevent from button:

```
void TestButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        loadimage = true;
    }
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm confused why this code works nasty:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var g = e.Graphics;
    g.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, pictureBox1.Width - pictureBox1.Image.Width, pictureBox1.Height - pictureBox1.Image.Height);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Ok now it works:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var image = Properties.Resources.SomeImage; //Import via Resource Manager
    //Don't use pictureBox1.Image property because it will
    //draw the image 2 times.
    //Make sure the pictureBox1.Image property is null in Deisgn Mode
    if (image != null)
    {
        var g = e.Graphics;
        // -- Optional -- //
        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        // -- Optional -- //
        g.DrawImage(image, 
            pictureBox1.Width - image.Width,  // to right
            pictureBox1.Height - image.Height, // to bottom
            image.Width,
            image.Height);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

> Working :) But is there any possibility to use this code without
>   PaintEventsArgs ? I was trying to add to my button flag and in paint
>   (if (flag==true) then execute Your code, but it doesn't do anything -
>   no drawing on picturebox1

That's because Paint event fires once. We need to make it redraw. The default redraw method for controls is `Refresh();`

Here you go:

```
bool flag = false;
Bitmap image = null;
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (flag && image != null)
    {
        var g = e.Graphics;
        // -- Optional -- //
        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        // -- Optional -- //
        g.DrawImage(image,
            pictureBox1.Width - image.Width,
            pictureBox1.Height - image.Height,
            image.Width,
            image.Height);
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    image = new Bitmap("someimage.png");
    flag = true;
    pictureBox1.Refresh(); //Causes it repaint.
}

//If you resize the form (and anchor/dock the picturebox) 
//or just resize the picturebox then you will need this:
private void pictureBox1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Because it resizes the image.

Comment: Working :) But is there any possibility to use this code without PaintEventsArgs ? I was trying to add to my button flag and in paint (if (flag==true) then execute Your code, but it doesn't do anything - no drawing on picturebox1.

Comment: Hmm, why don't you try hiding pictureBox1 and after clicking the button make it visible again by pictureBox1.Visible property?

Comment: Reviewed your code and made some changes. It seems you're loading image from harddisk.

Comment: Forgot about when the picturebox sizable or docked/anchored it will make trail. Updated, again :/

Answer (score 2):

You can use Bitmap + Graphics objects and copy the portion of your picture to a new bitmap (result) that will be assigned to the picturebox:

```
Size resultSize = new Size(100, 100);
Bitmap result = new Bitmap(resultSize.Width, resultSize.Height);
float left = yourbitmap.Width - resultSize.Width;
float top = yourbitmap.Height - resultSize.Height;
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
{
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.DrawImage(yourbitmap, left, top, resultSize.Width, resultSize.Height);
    g.Save();
}
```