# PictureBox Image Painted two times issue

Tags: c#, picturebox

I am loading multiple images into a pictureBox and is trying to centre it at the bottom. I am using the below function:

```
public void toogleImage(Boolean visible, Bitmap img)
{
  if (visible)
  {
    pict_statusCenter.Show();
    pict_statusCenter.Image = img;
  }
  else
  {
    pict_statusCenter.Hide();
  }
}
```

After reading several Q&A such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174910/how-to-put-image-aligned-right-bottom-in-picturebox), I have updated the paint event as below:

```
private void pict_statusCenter_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            var g = e.Graphics;
            g.DrawImage(pict_statusCenter.Image, 
                        (pict_statusCenter.Width - pict_statusCenter.Image.Width) / 2,
                         pict_statusCenter.Height - pict_statusCenter.Image.Height);
        }
```

The image is now painted at the right location of the picture box. The problem is that a duplicate of the image is painted in the top left corner. I am a bit lost, any clue?

Second question: my image is actually a gif. During debugging, I noticed that each gif update fires a paint event. Is that normal? Is this the right way to do it?

Thanks for your kind assistance.

Comment: The SO that you linked to also includes code to call Refresh() - are you doing that?

Comment: You need to learn the basics of PictureBox. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819440/painting-to-panel-after-update-call/29822012?s=1|0.0000#29822012) for a few hints about how to use it..

Comment: _each gif update_ What is that?

Comment: To center the image, if it is smaller than the pb set its SizeMode=CenterImage

Comment: It is just not correct code.  PictureBox already implements OnPaint and it draws the content of the Image property, paying attention to the SizeMode you selected.  Then it fires the Paint event and your event handler draws the image *again*, not paying attention to SizeMode.  And yes, the only way to animate a GIF is by painting each frame.  You are doing it wrong, it is entirely unclear *why* you are doing this.

Comment: Hi TaW thanks for your feedback, the pict_statusCenter.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage; does not allow the image to be positionned at the bottom. No I am not including a call to the refresh(). I have however tried now with no change.

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks for your so direct feedback. You seems to have the right understanding of the situation but I regret a bit that you did not share what was the best course of action :-/ Thanks anyway for confirming the GIF frame update.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally did a simple padding:

```
pict_statusCenter.Padding = new Padding(
  (pict_statusCenter.Width - pict_statusCenter.Image.Width)/2, 
  (pict_statusCenter.Height- pict_statusCenter.Image.Height),
  (pict_statusCenter.Width - pict_statusCenter.Image.Width)/2,
  0);
```